# How to prevent second for loop from slowing down data return from service

Tags: python, django, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore get data in my django application.

The query stream works just well.

I am trying to do some relation query, get the author of post from another table.

I am not sure if this is the way it's done with django.

Here is the code I have:

```
# Get Updates Method
def get_updates():
    # Get Updates From Firestore
    user_ref = firestore_client.collection('post')
    query = user_ref.where('status', '==', 'online').order_by('updatedAt', direction=firestore.Query.DESCENDING)

    # Updates Lists
    updates = []

    # For Loop to get stream into list and change date strings to django friendly
    for doc in query.stream():
        updates.append(doc.to_dict())
        for update in updates:
             # Get Update Author
             author_ref = firestore_client.collection('users').document(update['uid'])
             author = author_ref.get()
             if author.exists:
                update['name'] = author.get('displayName')
                update['avatar'] = author.get('photoURL')
             update['createdAt'] = datetime.strptime(doc.get('createdAt'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
             update['updatedAt'] = datetime.strptime(doc.get('updatedAt'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

The second for loop increases the load time. The page loads and I get the result I want but too slow.
What would be the efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered looking for an ORM for firestore?

Comment: Do you have any recommendations?